# Getting best_in_place gem to co-operate with Redcarpet markdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

For my markdown text i normally do the following on the text content(@user.content):

```
<%= raw Redcarpet.new(@user.content).to_html.html_safe %>
```

However i am now using the best_in_place gem like this

```
<%= best_in_place(@question, :statement, :path => {:controller => "users", :action => "update"}, :type => :textarea) %>
```

**How can i integrate Redcarpet with this?** i have tried this:

```
<%= Redcarpet.new(best_in_place(@question, :statement, :path => {:controller => "users", :action => "update"}, :type => :textarea)).to_html.html_safe %>
```

however the output is not what is expected. The best_in_place readme seems to point to a way to solve this, but i don't understand it [here](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place), under the section titled "Using custom display methods".  Can someone explain to me how i can make this work?

Answer (score 3):

I have never used the `best_in_place` gem, so I don't have tried it out. But from the documentation, you should do the following steps:

1. Add to the call to `best_in_place` the additional argument `:display_as`.
2. Implement the method referenced by `:display_as` in your model object.

Here are the details:

#### Additional argument

```
%= best_in_place(@question, :statement, :display_as => 'mk_statement', :path => {:controller => "users", :action => "update"}, :type => :textarea) %>
```

#### Implementation in the model

`class Question`

```
require 'redcarpet'

def mk_statement
   Redcarpet.new(self.statement).to_html.html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `display_with` attribute and pass it a `proc` like so:

```
<%= best_in_place(@question, :statement, :display_with => proc { |v| Redcarpet.new(v).to_html.html_safe, :path => {:controller => "users", :action => "update"}, :type => :textarea) %>
```